# Meeseeks: a natural species or completely synthetic?

Tags: rick-and-morty, meeseeks

I don't think it is addressed in the series but as I understand it they are summoned into existence and then disappear -- they do not go about their lives waiting for a task.

So it seems like they might have been created artificially entirely or they might have been adapted from a natural species to be meeseeks. (As a side note: they seem to have no moral code at all -- they will cheerfully kill upon the request of the summoner or even kill as they become more insane upon their own initiative. This absence of a code implies perhaps that they did not evolve naturally or if they did, they have been majorly fiddled with.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I’m Mister Meeseeks look at me - Meeseeks are artificial creations generated by the Meeseeks Boxes. Meeseeks are not born into this world fumbling for purpose, Jerry - They are CREATED, to serve a singular purpose for which they will go to any lengths to fulfill.

As of season 4, meeseeks are created by pushing the button on the meeseeks box, they have no lives outside of their task, do not exist until ‘summoned’, and cease to exist once their task is accomplished. Existence is described as painful, and existing for two or more days is described as an “eternity in meeseeks time”, and causes them to degrade mentally, become frustrated and depressed, and eventually suicidal/homicidal.

While one initially presses the button and orders the newly generated Meeseeks to “Kill HIM!” (‘Follow Through Meeseeks’), they eventually realize/knew all along that they cannot die until their task is accomplished. They are capable of retaining functionality after dismemberment or damage that would normally kill, but they are not gods or magic (something Rick disdains). This depiction is not always absolute in later episodes, where ‘Kill Nazi Morty Meeseeks’ does not immediately disappear after Rick’s spacecraft explosively decompresses and instead dies along with the other occupants in the void of space.. (Fans looking too deeply/nitpicking internal consistency is something the creator Dan Harmon disdains).

They have no internal organs or structures (reproductive or otherwise) and are filled with a white fluid, much like the synthetics from the Alien franchise, a series that the creator Dan Harmon references several times in the show. When we see a red meeseeks, it comes from a “Kirkland BRAND Meeseeks Box” - which heavily hints that both of these types of boxes are a common product created and sold somewhere in the multiverse, and not inventions of Rick’s.

Comment: while the synthetics in alien franchise have this white fluid they are also quite complex internally. not sure how meeseeks would work with only white fluid but maybe dan would of course disdain this question.

Comment: you mention they come into existence with a single purpose but actually, you do not seem to ask for specific thing until they already have come into existence. Therefore, every one of them seems to be almost infinitely skilled. (or at least very good teachers in every area -- perhaps, like the movie Seconds one could ask for something the Meeseeks could not do.